# Passar valor de textview para outra tela e converter para double novamente?

Tags: android-studio

Então eu tenho um valor armazenado em uma text view de um cálculo realizado anteriormente na activity 1 e necessito desse valor na activity 2 para realizar outros cálculos. Passar apenas o valor em String eu consigo passar, o que eu não consigo é converter para double e fazer os cálculos. Há e quando tentei passar para double assim como estar nas imagens o código esta funcionando, mas o valor que esta aparecendo e o valor 2 que define no default value.

Seguem os códigos-fontes.

Código da Activity 1:

```
public void padiola (View v){




    Intent telapad = new Intent(this,Padiola.class);
    telapad.putExtra("chavea",vua.getText().toString());
    telapad.putExtra("chaveb",vub.getText().toString());
    startActivity(telapad);







}
```

}

Código da Activity 2:

```
TextView qtda, qtdb, alta, altb, vuar, vubr;


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_padiola);





    qtda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtdPadareia);
    qtdb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtdPadbrita);
    alta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altAreia);
    altb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altBrita);
    vuar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.novoVA);
    vubr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.novoVB);



   Double va = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("chavea",2f);
   Double vb = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("chaveb",2f);


    vuar.setText(Double.toString(va));
    vubr.setText(Double.toString(vb));




}

public void trintaxquarenta(View v) {

    //Para Areia//

    double s1 = Double.parseDouble(vuar.getText().toString());
    double s2 = Double.parseDouble(vubr.getText().toString());

    double s3 = s1 + s2;

    qtda.setText(Double.toString(s3));

}
```

}

Comment: Ola, tudo bem? Por gentileza, voce conseguiria postar os códigos ao invés de imagens? Seria mais util e pratico.

Comment: consigo sim !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue pegar o valor na segunda activity pois estás passando uma String da activity A para a B e na activity B está tentando pegar um Double ao invés de uma String. Quando chegar na segunda activity, deverá primeiro utilizar o método getStringExtra() e depois converter o valor obtido para Double conforme desejado.
Exemplo:

```
Double va = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("chavea"));
Double vb = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("chaveb"));
```

Isso deverá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Então, testei dessa forma e não funcionou. Quando clico no botão para a ir até a activity B o app fecha. Tentei pegar como String e depois converter e tambem não funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Opa, blza?!
Como teve dúvidas de onde e quando recuperar os valores na sua activity A, postei o código completo.

> Na sua Activity A:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declarando os campos de valores
    EditText valor1, valor2;
    //Botao para a proxima intent
    Button botaoProximaIntent;
    //valores double para a proxima intent
    double a, b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        valor1 = findViewById(R.id.valor1);
        valor2 = findViewById(R.id.valor2);
        botaoProximaIntent = findViewById(R.id.botaoProximaIntent);
        //click no botao
        botaoProximaIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //faça as validacoes antes de pegar os valores
                //resgate seu double A do editText
                a = Double.parseDouble(valor1.getText().toString());
                //resgate seu double A do editText
                b = Double.parseDouble(valor2.getText().toString());

                //agora temos o valor de a e b, vamos chamar a proxima intent e passar os parametros
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                //declaramos o bundle
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                //parametros do bundle
                params.putDouble("valor1", a);
                params.putDouble("valor2", b);
                intent.putExtras(params);
                //chamamos a proxima intent
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Na sua Activity B, receba os valores:

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);
        //declarando os valores
        double a, b;
        // pegando os parametros intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //validando a intent
        if (intent != null)
        {
            Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
            //validando se há parametros
            if  (params != null)
            {
                //resgatando os valores na segunda intent
                a = params.getDouble("valor1");
                b = params.getDouble("valor2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]